# using %union for structs

Tags: c++, struct, bison

I searched a lot but can't seem to find a clear example on how to use %union is my parser file.
I would like to save for example the following token in a struct called classID:

```
[a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*            { yylval=new IDClass(yytext); return ID; }
```

This is the struct in my `.hpp` folder which I included:

```
class Node {
    public:
       Node(){}
    };


    class IDClass : public Node {
    public:
        string name;
        IDClass(string name):
        Node(),name(name)
        {}
    };
```

& then in my `.ypp` file , I would like to use it for certain checking:

```
Define: Type ID { if(doesIDexists(***$2->name***)){errorDef(yylineno, ID_ptr->name);exit(1);}}
```

But obviously, $2->name won't return it. What is the correct use of %union in structs? How can I grab the value of name properly?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "correct use of `%union` in structs", since `%union` is used to declare a `union`. (You could, of course, declare a `union` with just one member, but that's almost pointless.)

The correct way of declaring a semantic type which is not a `union` is:

```
%define api.value.type { Node* }
```

But that's not going to get you want, since what you want is neither a `union` nor a fixed type, but rather an implicit dynamic cast, or something similar. And that's not on Bison's menu of options. (It's easy to see why not. The dynamic cast wouldn't be an lvalue so Bison would have to know when to apply it and when not to.)

So you could use the above `%define api.value.type` and then write out the grammar action:

```
Define: Type ID { if (doesIDexist(dynamic_cast<IDClass>($2)->name)) {
                        errorDef(@2.first_line,
                                 dynamic_cast<IDClass>($2)->name);
                        exit(1);
                      }
                }
```

If you generate a C++ parser instead of a C parser which happens to work in C++, then you have some other options, which might or might not be a better fix for your application. The options for a C parser are explained in the [Language Semantics](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Semantics) chapter of the Bison manual, and the C++ options have [their own chapter](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#C_002b_002b-Semantic-Values), although if you are going to use the C++ interface you need to read the entire C++ section.

Note: I changed `yylineno` to `@2.first_line` because `yylineno` is usually inaccurate; `yylineno` is often the line number associated with the lookahead token, which is often not on the same line as the error. But you can't just make that change; you also have to make sure that your lexer fills in `yylloc` correctly. See the [Tracking Locations](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/bison.html#Tracking-Locations) chapter in the Bison manual.